# Как найти дочерний объект и отключить его, а через некоторое время опять включить?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
public class SpwnEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject SpwnEff;

    void Start ()
    {
        SpwnEff.SetActive(false);
    }   

    void Update ()
    {
        if (transform.position.y < -20)
        {            
            SpwnEff.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(DisableSpwnEff(2.0f));            
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisableSpwnEff(float sec)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
        SpwnEff.SetActive(false);
    }    
}
```

Но условия изменились и "SpwnEff" больше не публичный объект, а назначаемый другим скриптом. И теперь их много и с разными именами. Теперь этот объект дочерний.
Нужно в скрипте, который "повиснет" на "родителе" обратится к дочерним объектам - на старте - отключить их. Затем при условии `transform.position.y < -20` - включить - и через секунду - опять отключить. Этот процесс должен быть повторяемым. Речь идёт о персонаже, на котором висит префаб - эффект вспышки. Когда персонаж появляется на сцене - префаб отключён - когда проваливается вниз, до отметки -20 - префаб должен включаться (другой скрипт возвращает персонажа на чек-поинт и по задумке, должна произойти вспышка), а затем, через пару секунд, префаб надо отключить - что б, при следующем падении он опять сработал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить список "детей" данного объекта, можно использовать такой подход:

```
foreach(Transform child in transform) {
    // итерируемся по всем детям
    // для получения именно объекта ребенка - используем child.gameObject
}
```

Чтобы выключить/включить всех детей, проще написать метод, используя код выше:

```
void SetChildrenActiveState(bool active) {
    foreach(Transform child in transform) {
        child.gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }
}
```

Также надо понимать, что условие `if (transform.position.y < -20)` будет каждый кадр возвращать true после преодоления объектом высоты в -20f. Поэтому желательно завести какой-нибудь флаг, если же таких "состояний" больше 2, то лучше завести конечный автомат, но это уже совсем другая история.

Ну и наконец, финальный код:

```
public class ChildrenActivator : MonoBehaviour {   
    bool ready = true;

    void Start() {
        SetChildrenActiveState(false);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (ready && transform.position.y <= -20f) {
            StartCoroutine(DisableSpwnEff(1.0f));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisableSpwnEff(float sec) {
        ready = false;
        SetChildrenActiveState(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
        ready = true;
        SetChildrenActiveState(false);
    }

    void SetChildrenActiveState(bool active) {
        foreach(Transform child in transform) {
            child.gameObject.SetActive(active);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, за ответ. К сожалению не заработало... Ошибок никаких не выдало - буду искать в чем проблема.

Comment: Что значит "не заработало", этот код проверен на моей машине. Вы уверены, что вы **верно** задали вопрос?

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь в правильности Вашего кода. Видимо, в проекте есть ещё какие то условия, о которых я не знаю, и которые не позволяют срабатывать скрипту. Иерархия имеет значение? Ну, т.е. тот объект, который я назвал "родительским" - на самом деле сам дочерний.

Comment: Так я ничего против и не имею, я пытаюсь вам помочь и то, что у вас протесченный код не работает, удивило меня, от чего я и попросил подробностей проекта) Если родительский объект имеет детей и при этом сам является чьи-то потомком, то данный код все равно будет работать.

Comment: Я менял значение "transform.position.y < -5f" на "-20f" - и не срабатывало вообще. При вашем значении -5f или при -19f - срабатывает 1 раз. При повторных падениях персонажа - скрипт не срабатывает. Дочерний остаётся не активным.

Comment: В смысле, вы же сказали, что вам нужно ровно 1 раз включить и через секунду выключить объект, вот он и срабатывает 1 раз.

Comment: Получается, что я не верно сформулировал вопрос. Подумал, по скрипту понятно будет )) Извиняюсь. Этот процесс должен повторятся. Речь про эффект вспышки при возвращении персонажа на чекпоинт - после падения. Т.е. - он падает до -20 по Y - и тут же возвращается на чекпоинт.

Comment: Внесите все правки в сам вопрос, что за чекпоинт, что за эффект вспышки - все это трактовать можно по-разному, поэтому я не могу дать точный ответ.

Comment: @Кирилл дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное - всё работает!